# Android webview video tag screenshot white screen

Tags: javascript, android, video, webview

I would like to take screenshot from the stream in `<video>` tag in webview.

I've created simple project with webview control inside framelayout. In the manifest I've added line:
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Configuration of webview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 5);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    String sDataPath = getApplicationContext().getDir("databases", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(sDataPath);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(mWebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url,
                                            String databaseIdentifier, long quota,
                                            long estimatedDatabaseSize, long totalQuota,
                                            WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {

            quotaUpdater.updateQuota(5 * 1024 * 1024);
        }
    });
    WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                 ...
        }
    };
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(client);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/video.html");
    super.onResume();
}
```

Android tested solutions:

1.

```
public static Bitmap screenshot(WebView webView) {
    try {
        float scale = webView.getScale();
        int height = (int) (webView.getContentHeight() * scale + 0.5);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        webView.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

2.

```
public static Bitmap screenshot2(WebView webView) {
        webView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight());
        webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                webView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int iHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, iHeight, paint);
        webView.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

3.

```
 Picture picture = mWebView.capturePicture();
                Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth() / 2, picture.getHeight() / 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(b1);
                mWebView.draw(c);
```

4.

```
        View view = mWebView.getRootView();
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

5.

```
@Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Picture picture = mWebView.capturePicture();
                        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(),
                                picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                        picture.draw(c);
...
```

All of above solutions I save to file by this method:

```
public static Bitmap saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
FileOutputStream fos1 = null;
                try {

                    fos1 = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + filename);
                    if (fos1 != null) {
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos1);

                        fos1.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
}
```

HTML file with Javascript solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="input" width="250" height="250">
        <video width="250" height="250" id="video" controls>
            <source src=http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4 type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
    <div id="output" width="250" height="250">
        <button id="snap" onclick="snap()">Snap Photo</button>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
            var video = document.querySelector('video');
            var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var w, h, ratio;

            video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
                ratio = video.videoWidth / video.videoHeight;

                w = video.videoWidth - 100;
                h = parseInt(w / ratio, 10);

                canvas.width = w;
                canvas.height = h;
            }, false);

            function snap() {
                        context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
                        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
            }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Above solutions has been tested at 8 phones (range from Android 4.4 to 6.0), but in all of them, android solutions didn't work. It depends on the solution but basically I have got file with the view of 'snap' button, video player elements and white screen in the view of stream. Javascript solution work in the half of devices, but without any connection to the version of Android. I also changed video type but without success.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I figured out that the problem is with the version of webview: Unfortunately google's remote webview updating works only on nexuses and a few others phones in which the phone manufacturer doesn't change webview configuration. Links to this information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352636/html5-video-draw-into-canvas2d-issue-on-android-chrome  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139413/android-system-webview-installed-but-not-used-by-apps

Comment: Same problem, no solution so far...